# CMOS Analog Multiplexer SPDT

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, analog, multiplexer

I have tried to use the QS4A205 (a CMOS ANALOG FOUR-CHANNEL SPDT MUX) where 2 buffered DAC outputs are connected to the SPDT inputs and the output of the MUX is connected to a low current draw node (max 10mA). Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get this working and I believe that I am missing something in my schematics.

This image shows a description of what I have tried but did not get it to work. Can anyone please be kind as to suggestions on getting this to work? Also, do I need to have the transmission lines in and out of the MUX matched to a 50 ohm impedance?

I appreciate any help with this, thank you.

Here's a link to the datasheet [QS4A205 Datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/qs4a205-datasheet)

[image: Schematic]

EDIT: here is the initial schematic design, the less detailed schematic above was done on breadboard not as a pcb.
[image: Initial PCB schematic]

Comment: Well, there's a lot missing from your schematic including the power pins and control pins. And even the pin names of the pins that are shown are missing (or at least, do not match those in the datasheet).

Comment: @DKNguyen my apologies, i've attached the full schematic. thanks.

Comment: The datasheet says (top of page 3) that the analogue signal voltage range is from -0.5V to +4V, when used with a 5V supply. Are you complying with this condition?

Comment: @SimonFitch yes, i am. my application involves 0V - 3.3V. do you think it would be necessary to include series and parallel resistors to the input and output of the mux?

Comment: @user49706 No, not necessarily, unless they are to scale the input voltage to be within those voltage constraints, or there's something else you're not saying. For instance, unless you tell people the source and purpose of your signals, and what frequencies you expect them to be, it's not possible to say whether you need to consider transmission lines or 50Ω termination. These considerations are almost certainly not the cause of your problems though. As to why it's not working with *any* signal, it's not clear to me.

Comment: @user49706 In a test setup, all those resistors are just muddying the water. I would stick that MUX in a breadboard, under the most basic conditions of simple input voltages, and get it working there first. At least you'll know if it's toast or not.

Comment: Yeah strip down your circuit and check. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the schematic so probably wiring mistake.